# Sharepoint workbench page with NoComponentId error

Tags: spfx, spfx-webparts, spfx-tooling

So I did basic hello webpart setting and ran gulp which shown me SP framework local page.

Now i wanted to see this in sharepoint context , so

1. I copied workbench.aspx from https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/blob/master/workbench.aspx
2. Uploaded this to Shared documents in my Developer site in sharepoint online.
3. I expected to browse workbench page by clicking on it, however i am seeing below issue when clicked on workbench aspx, any input please, what i have done wrong? (I am not at the step where i am supposed to tell browser to load script safely.)
   [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you make sure below step is performed in Document library

Enter ClientSideApplicationId as the column name and leave the other fields at their current values.
Choose OK to create the column.

Comment: thank you. I was referring this and dint find anywhere mentioned that column needs to be created . https://dev.office.com/sharepoint/docs/spfx/web-parts/get-started/connect-to-sharepoint . I just create column and it worked.

Comment: That instruction is in [Set up your Office 365 developer tenant](https://dev.office.com/sharepoint/docs/spfx/set-up-your-developer-tenant) which all the Getting Started assumes

Comment: Both of the links in comments above are dead. Are there other references?